# Reading value from field variable

Tags: java, multithreading, field

I am developing desktop app in Java 7. I have here a situation. At the method below

```
private synchronized void decryptMessage
    (CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> possibleKeys, ArrayList<Integer> cipherDigits)
{
    // apply opposite shift algorithm:
    ArrayList<Integer> textDigits = shiftCipher(possibleKeys, cipherDigits);

    // count CHI squared statistics:
    double chi = countCHIstatistics(textDigits);

    if(chi < edgeCHI) // if the value of IOC is greater or equal than that
    {
        System.err.println(chi + " " + possibleKeys + " +");
        key = possibleKeys; // store most suitable key
        edgeCHI = chi;
    }       
}
```

I count the value called 'chi' and based on that if 'chi' is less than 'edgeCHI' value I save the key at instance variable. That method is invoked by some threads, so I enforce synchronization.

When all the threads complete the program continues to execute by passing control to a method which controls the sequence of operations. Then this line has been executed at that method:

```
System.err.println(edgeCHI+" "+key+" -");
```

It prints correct value of 'chi', as has been printed the last value of 'chi' at `decryptMessage` method, but the value of key is different. The 'decryptMessage' method has been invoked by threads which generate key values.

I store the key value as global variable
 `private volatile CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> key = null; // stores the most suitable key for decryption`.
Why do I have two different key values? The values itself are not important. The matter is that the value of key printed at the last call at 'decryptMessage' method (when chi < edgeCHI) must match the one printed at the method which controls the flow of operations. 
This is how you create **threads**:

```
for(int y = 0; y < mostOccuringL.length; y++){// iterate through the five most frequent letters
                for(int i = (y + 1); i < mostOccuringL.length; i++ ){//perform letter combinations
                    int [] combinations = new int[2];
                    combinations[0] = y;
                    combinations [1] = i;                   
                    new KeyMembers(""+y+":"+i ,combinations, keywords, intKeyIndex, cipherDigits).t.join();
                }
            }
```

Within run method you invoke *decryptMesssage* method in order to identify most feasible decryption key.
I have been trying to figure out what is the prob for two days, but I don't get it.
Suggestions?

Comment: What did you expect as output?? And what you got?? We don't know what two different key values you are talking about..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been found. I just changed **CopyOnWriteArrayList** data type into ArrayList at the point where field variable gets correct key. It works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on syserr (or sysout) printing to determine an order of execution is dangerous - especially in multi-threaded environments. There is absolutely no guarantuee when the printing actually occurs or if the printed messages are in order. Maybe what you see as "last" printed message of one of the threads wasn't the "last" thread modifying the key field. You cannot say that by looking only at sterr output.

What you could do is use a synchronized setter for the key field, that increases an associated access counter whenever the field is modified and print the new value along with the modification count. This way you can avoid the problems of syserr printing and reliably determine what the last set value was. e.g. :

```
private long keyModCount = 0;

private synchronized long update(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> possibilities, double dgeChi) {
   this.keys = possibilites;
   this.edgeChi = edgeChi;   // how is edgeChi declared? Also volatile?
   this.keyModCount++;
   return this.keyModCount;
}
```

And inside decryptMessage:

```
if(chi < edgeCHI) // if the value of IOC is greater or equal than that
{
   long sequence = update(possibleKeys, chi); 
   System.err.println("["+ sequence +"]"+ chi + " " + possibleKeys + " +");
}
```

To provide an answer we would need to see more of the (simplified if necessary) code that controls the thread execution.

Comment: The 'edgeCHI' has not been declared as 'volatile' but surprisingly it stores right value as the one at 'decryptMessage' method's sterr out stream. Your suggestion to create the synchronized update method does not make a difference.

Comment: Judging from the code you showed, there is no way the update method changes the resulting field values. Its only purpose is to generate a sequence number to establish a total ordering on the syserr output for changes to the involved variables. I would still set my bets on an "unexpected" reordering of thread execution as the cause, but unless you provide a broader overview of the execution flow and the intended outcome it's hard to reveal it. Did you check for modifications to the keys field (or the list stored there!) in other parts of your code?

Comment: when multiple threads run in parallel and concurrently modify data the order of the modifications is unspecified unless the threads are synchronized. Therefore you could be misled by the syserr statements that the last value should be value A, but in reality it was modified by another thread to be value B. Furthermore changes by parallel threads may not be visible to other threads unless there is a synchronization point. So you could see or determine that a thread set a field to value A but another thread could not "see" this modification (possibly forever)